# Writing a test program to evaluate the computational complexity(Big O)

Tags: big-o

I was task with a problem to write a test program to evaluate the computational complexity (Big O) of the following problem and really dont know where to start.

1. A single loop iterated n times
2. A nested loop where eaach loop is iterated n times

This is what I was able to produce

```
for(int i=0; i <n; i++){
   // Do stuff
}
```

The problem now is how to write the test program. Can someone help me out?

Comment: C-language? you're on the right track. Read more about big-o here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o

Comment: You can't really "evaluate the computational complexity", as big-O notation is defined in terms of the *asymptotic* performance (i.e. it's an algebraic expression for the behaviour as `n` goes to infinity).  However, you could run your program for different values of `n`, time it, and plot the results.  Is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you described, the complexity of the algo seems to be O(n ^ 2).
It can be possible to try evaluating it "experimentally": just run the algo with different n values and take the computation times. Then plot the n values on the x axis of a graph and the time values on the y axis. You should now see something approximable with a parabola.

Answer (score 0):

For problems with complexities of the form (n^k) where k>=0 , code can be written by counting number of nested loops . But it's difficult to implement in recursive problems with "complex"
complexities ( (n^2)*lg(n) ).

I have not implemented it ,but i am sure ,can be done